# 配列の値が昇順に並べ替えられる様子を確認したい

Tags: c

配列の値を昇順に並べ替える関数 `ssort` を以下のように作成したのですが、配列の値が昇順に並べられる様子がわかりません。

例えば `4 3 1 5 2` では、どのような順序で `1 2 3 4 5` と並べ替えられますか。

```
void swap(int *x,int*y)
{
   int tmp;
   tmp=*x;
   *x=*y;
   *y=tmp;
}

void ssort(int a[],int size)
{
   int i,j,min;
   for(j=0;j<size-1;j++){
      min=j;
      for(i=j+1;i<size;i++){
         if(a[i]<a[min])  min=i;
      }
      swap(&a[j],&a[min]);
   }
}
```

Comment: 答えてはありませんが、swap関数を通るたびにaの内容をprintすればどのような順序になっているかわかると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

池田茂樹さんのコメントにある通り、
以下のように `printf()` で出力すれば、途中の様子を見ることができます。

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_process(int a[], int size)
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      printf("%d ", a[i]);
   printf("\n");
}

void swap(int *x,int*y)
{
   int tmp;
   tmp=*x;
   *x=*y;
   *y=tmp;
}

void ssort(int a[],int size)
{
   int i,j,min;
   print_process(a, size);
   for(j=0;j<size-1;j++){
      min=j;
      for(i=j+1;i<size;i++){
         if(a[i]<a[min])  min=i;
      }
      swap(&a[j],&a[min]);
      print_process(a, size);
   }
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[5] = {4, 3, 1, 5, 2};

    ssort(a, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

結果は以下のようになりました。

```
luna:~ % ./test                 
4 3 1 5 2 
1 3 4 5 2 
1 2 4 5 3 
1 2 3 5 4 
1 2 3 4 5 
luna:~ %
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「aの内容をprintする」とは、どういうことかわかりませんでしたが、masmさんの上記の説明で理解できました。